# MySQL: Use trigger to update table with time.now

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL table which stores a list of dates/times in the format 2013-12-21 12:15:00. I would like to write a trigger to update another column (from false to true) when the system time is equal to time stored in the db. The state should then not be altered by the trigger once time.now is greater then the current system time.

I've never used triggers however I tried to write the following code but it didn't work. If anyone would point my in the right direction that would be great.

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `update_time` AFTER INSERT 
ON `time_table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF time_table.start_time = time.now THEN SET time_table.state = True;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually require a `BEFORE` trigger on the table.

The following should work.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `update_time` BEFORE INSERT ON `time_table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.start_time = NOW() THEN SET NEW.state = True;  
END;

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks but I just get the error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END;' at line 4'